# Laravel, reverse proxy: css, js and image files are not obtained

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

I'm learning Lavarel and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve it.

In an internal network I have the machine **http://caption-t3/** with a Laravel application. Users access to the laravel application through the URL: **https://www.my-domain.com/app/t3/portal**.

A reverse proxy redirects all requests from **https://www.my-domain.com/app/t3/portal** to **http://caption-t3/**. I don't have access to the reverse proxy configuration

The problem is that the content is obtained but not the css, js and images files. I don't know if it's a problem with the **.htaccess** file (an apache server is used and I don't know how to configure the .htaccess files) or with Laravel configuration.

Can anyone give me guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: If you think it's a problem with `.htaccess` then we would need to see your `.htaccess` file(s). However, there's no real information here to even guess what is happening? How is the server configured? What is your URL structure, how are you linking to assets? How is the request being proxied?

Comment: "*...but not the css, js and images files*" - what happens for them? 404s? Some other error?  What does your browser devtools/network tab show for those requests? Do you have access to the logs from the proxy? What do the logs for Apache on your Laravel server show?  Can you share the proxy configuration here?

Comment: The configuration of apache was wrong. DocumentRoot was assigned the wrong path.